# mongoengine query to nested listfield

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I made article system with python flask.

To communicate with mongodb, use `flask_mongoengine`

Here is my model.

```
class SubComment(EmbeddedDocument):
    no = SequenceField()
    body = StringField()

class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    no = SequenceField()
    body = StringField()
    sub_comment = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(SubComment))


class Article(Document):
    title = StringField()
    body = StringField()
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
```

`SubComment` model stored into `Comment` model and `Comment` model stored into `Article` model.

So, this is the output that I want.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c0641d81b48d9fe50dfdd7f"),
    "title" : "test",
    "body" : "gogo",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "no" : 1,
            "body" : "first comment",
            "sub_comment" : [
                   {
                        "no": 1,
                        "body": "sub comm"
                   }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I insert `Comment` model to `Article` model, just use below code.

```
comment = Comment(
    body='first comment'
)
article = Article.objects(body='gogo').first()
article.comments.append(comment)
article.save()
```

But when I try to insert `SubComment` to `Comment`, it throw errors -> `AttributeError: 'BaseList' object has no attribute 'sub_comment'`

Below is the code I used.

```
comment = SubComment(
    body='sub comment'
)
article = Article.objects(title='test', comments__no=1).first()
article.comments.sub_comment.append(comment)
article.save()
```

After some searched, people said there is no way to insert nested field.

Is there any solution here? I have to use raw query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I solved with `for` loop like this.

```
count = 0
article = Article.objects(title='test', comments__no=1).first()
for comment in article.comments:
    if comment.no == 1:
        print(comment.no)
        count = comment.no - 1

article.comments[count].sub_comment.append(sub_comment)
article.save()
```

But I don't know it is the right way.

If you have any other solution, please comment it.